# Partial render not working on ajax call rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, haml, renderpartial

I am trying to reload a partial with a page (not the whole) page when I click on a button. When i click on button reset_me, it should reload the partial. Even though the partial is being called, the javascript inside js.haml is not executed.

routes

```
post :reset_filter, defaults: { format: 'js' }
```

controller action

```
def reset_filter
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render 'reset_filter.js.haml', layout: false }
  end
end
```

inside reset_filter.js.haml

```
$("#reset_me").html("#{j render partial: 'reset'}")
$('#reset_me").text('i have reset') // does not work as well
```

reset.html.haml

```
= button_tag 'Reset me', type: 'submit', disabled: false, id: 'reset_me'
```

show.html.haml

```
= render 'reset'
```

Javascript to trigger ajax call

```
reloadSidebar() {
  const requestInit = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    credentials: 'include',
    body: {}
  }

  fetch('full_controller_path', requestInit);
}

const resetAllElement = document.getElementById('reset_me');
.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  reloadSidebar();
})
```

When I click the text should change. I traced it in console and it executes the .js.haml file, but javascript is not executed. Response from API also returns html with correct information ie. full html. Can someone help me find missing puzzle?

Comment: you could try replace `format.js { render 'reset_filter.js.haml', layout: false }` by only `format.js`

Comment: @LamPhan yeah that was my first try. That did not even go inside reset_filter.js.haml. Had to use layout: false to trigger it.

Comment: let try another `respond_to do |format| format.js end`

Comment: @LamPhan Sorry that was my mistake, in the code it is already as you suggested. I have edited the question as well.

Comment: i think your problem is not about render partial but about `ujs`, you could try use [button-to](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#button-to) instead of call ajax yourself

Comment: @LamPhan I have to do other things in javascript, so using button-to would not be good fit in this case. The example above is a very simplified version.

Comment: If you remove `$("#reset_me").html("#{j render partial: 'reset'}")` does the second line work? Or if you put a simple alert or console.log, does it render? If yes then you definitely have an error in the reset partial.

Comment: @razvans console.log does not render also the text does not change. JavaScript simply does not execute. If I put binding.pry, then it stops in the partial. So it goes through the partial.

Answer (score 0):

so your problem is not about render partial views but your js response is not executed, and you don't want to use `ujs`

i think you could use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) to execute js response

fetch (base on your code)

```js
fetch('full_controller_path', {
  method: 'POST', 
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: ...
})
.then(response => eval(response))
```

ajax

```js
$('reset_me').bind('ajax:complete', function(event, xhr, status) {
 if (xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type').match("text/javascript")) {
   eval(xhr.responseText);
 }
  // ...
});
```

Note: there's warning **Never use eval()!**, and you also have another choice, just return `json` data instead of `js` and handle json response by js code on front end.